# Pytorch Feature Scaling within the Model or within the Dataloader

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to conduct a simple feature scaling in PyTorch. For example, I have an image, and I want to scale certain pixel values down by 10. Now I have 2 options:

1. Directly divide those features by 10.0 in `__getitem__` function in dataloader;
2. Pass the original features into the model forward function, but before pass them through trainable layers, scale down the corresponding features.

I have conducted several experiments, but observed after the first epoch, the validation losses between the two would start to diverge slightly. While after a couple hundreds of epochs, the two trained models would vary largely. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Scaling usually goes into transforms applied on the dataset (see [this](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html)).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.